# empty list when cycling in a tuple

Tags: python, tuples, lexer

```
def calcCandidates(str):
    TOKEN_CONFIG = [
    ("Mor", af.automata_Mor(str))]
    for (TokenKind, automata) in TOKEN_CONFIG:
       candidates.append(TokenKind)
    return (allTrapped, candidates)
```

I do get a reply and is this:
(False, [])

But I'm expecting to have something inside [], for example ["mor"]

If you need the full code of that function:

```
def calcCandidates(str):
    TOKEN_CONFIG = [
    ("Mor", af.automata_Mor(str)),
    ("Si", af.automata_Si(str)),
    ("Hacer", af.automata_Hacer(str)),
    ("OpenC", af.automata_OpenC(str)),
    ("CloseC", af.automata_CloseC(str)),

    ]

    allTrapped = True
    candidates = []

    for (TokenKind, automata) in TOKEN_CONFIG:

        res = automata
        
        if res == RESULT_ACCEPTED:
            allTrapped = False
            candidates.append(TokenKind)
        if res == RESULT_NOT_ACCEPTED:
            allTrapped = False

    return (allTrapped, candidates)
```

Comment: Can you give more context on what's happening in the function?

Comment: I edited giving the full function

Comment: You'll get that result if none of the automata are `RESULT_ACCEPTED`.

Comment: And at least one of them are `RESULT_NOT_ACCEPTED`.

Comment: Use `print(TOKEN_CONFIG)` to see if there's any `RESULT_ACCEPTED`.

Comment: But even if I force it to be RESULT_ACCEPTED I do get an empty list

Comment: I will try to print then @Barmar

Comment: Why do you need `res = automata`? Just use `if automata == ...`

Comment: Also, you should use `elif` for mutually exclusive tests.

Comment: I tried printing and they are all unexpectedly NOT ACCEPTED. So i'm gonna try solving that first, You helped a lot